# iPhone 5S - Possible Depth Buffer issue

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

In my application, I render plane over plane. Lower plane has Z = 0, second one has Z = 0.5. If I render them (lower first), I got missing part of render, as shown on picture

[image]

On iPhone 4 and desktop (using ES emulator), there is everything correct and no problem. What could cause this bevaiour ?

Same problem occurs also for other parts of scene, like tracks, tubes (green and blue on this picture). Problem occurs, when I move camera

Comment: Can you try decreasing the zFar parameter in glFrustum or any similar call and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @MaticOblak I have tried decrise zFar from 600 (too much) to 150 and zNear from 0.3 to 2, but problem persist. Plus, if it were caused by this, I believe, that iPhone 4 would have similar issues

Comment: There can be differences depending on the hardware. In any case it is very hard to debug this seeing only 2 images. Try pinpointing the issue to depth at first: If you remove the grid on the 2nd image it should show a lightened rectangle on the borders as the depth on 2nd plane should be a bit nearer (if not the precision is too low and you need to decrease the zFar); if possible try using another format for the depth buffer; try using GL_LEQUAL or GL_GEQUAL on depth checks; make a shader to output the colour depending on Z check for 2nd surface (red if it fails and green if it succeeds)...

Comment: I am using 24bit depth buffer, with GL_GREATER (or GL_GEQUAL). If i increase zNear, geometry in distance starts to disappear. I have checked depth buffer output and it seems, that values for 2nd plane are not written.

Comment: I can see they are not written. I meant you to use GL_ALWAYS and do the Z check manually but never mind that, this will be much easier: Before the second plane draw make a constant switch for the depth check. Swap between GL_GEQUAL and GL_LESS every 10 frames. If the depth check is making the issue you should see the exact negative when "less" is displayed. Use something like this: 
static int mode = 0; 
mode=(mode+1)%100; 
if((mode/10) % 2) ;//use greater 
else ;//use lesser 
//draw plane 
//reset depth check

Comment: If I use less, I see only first plane and not the second one. So basicly "negative"

Comment: Well, no. If when you use "greater" there are peaces missing on the second plane you should see those peaces using "less". This means the depth buffer is not the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok... I have solved this. There was problem in my shader that caused depth buffer to be filled incorectly.
I have used

```
precision mediump float;
```

and that caused geometry to be not precise and Z = 0 vs Z = 0.5 has been mixed together.

Changing precision to `highp` solved the issue.

Bottom line. This "optimalization" was huge mistake and never use mediump in Vertex Shader (unless you are facing some performance impact and even that its not worth it. The difference in rendering is not noticable)

Comment: Thanks for that info, I'll definitely not use mediump after reading your experience. At the moment, I am just learning OpenGL ES 2.0, still stuck in years-past OpenGL ES 1.1

Answer (score 1):

(This is in response to your own answer, which is only partially correct)

You've got a case of Z-fighting going on, due to the mapping of your scene's Z values, to the z-buffer. This may be a non-linear mapping (1/f(Z) is common), but I'm not sure on floating point z-buffers.

Your scene is really simple, and while chunking more z-buffer range at the problem is a partial solution, it's at the cost of performance, and not really understanding the issue. You may well run into this same problem again even with the highest possible precision z-buffer you can use on your platform!

Look at your scenes; you want to map the z-range in the 3D scene, to the maximum possible range of values the z-buffer can store, else you're wasting chunks of the range of numbers the z-buffer can store. Calculating this mapping per-frame can be useful, depending on what you want to do with the z-buffer later on.

Have a look [here](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html) for some calculations. Note, that with a floating point z-buffer, you may well be worse off than with an integer one if you're chucking away a lot of small numbers - that's where the vast majority of possible storable values of a floating point number are!

Comment: Thank you... I know, there are different depth mapping, but for such an easy scene, I want to keep things as simple as possible (other words, use classic depth buffer). Plus, even if I change mapping, problem with mediump can be there again.